# Efficient way of merging data frames on custom conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Below are the below data frames i have esh -> earnings surprise history 
and sph-> stock price history.

earnings surprise history

```
    ticker   reported_date reported_time_code  eps_actual
0    ABC     2017-10-05       AMC                1.01
1    ABC     2017-07-04       BMO                0.91
2    ABC     2017-03-03       BMO                1.08
3    ABC     2016-10-02       AMC                0.5
```

stock price history

```
    ticker       date    adj_open   ad_close
0    ABC     2017-10-06   12.10      13.11      
1    ABC     2017-12-05   11.11      11.87     
2    ABC     2017-12-04   12.08      11.40     
3    ABC     2017-12-03   12.01      13.03 
..
101  ABC     2017-07-04   9.01        9.59
102  ABC     2017-07-03   7.89        8.19
```

I like to build a new dataframe by merging two datasets which shall have the following columns as shown below and also if the reported_time_code from the earnings surprise history is **AMC**  then the record to be referred from stock price history should be the next day.if the reported_time_code is **BM0**  then record to be referred from stock price history should be the same day. if i used straight merge function on the actual_reported column of esh and data column of sph it will break the above conditions. looking for efficient way of transforming the data

Here is the resultant transformed data set

```
    ticker       date     adj_open   ad_close  eps_actual
0    ABC     2017-10-06    12.10      13.11      1.01  
101  ABC     2017-07-04    9.01        9.59      0.91
```

Comment: @ScottBoston corrected it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add a new column, 'date', to stock price history dataframe based on reported_time_code using `np.where` and `drop` unwanted columns then `merge` to earning history dataframe:

```
eh['reported_date'] = pd.to_datetime(eh.reported_date)

sph['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sph.date)

eh_new = eh.assign(date=np.where(eh.reported_time_code == 'AMC',
                                 eh.reported_date + pd.DateOffset(days=1),
                                 eh.reported_date)).drop(['reported_date','reported_time_code'],axis=1)

sph.merge(eh_new, on=['ticker','date'])
```

Output:

```
  ticker       date  adj_open  ad_close  eps_actual
0    ABC 2017-10-06     12.10     13.11        1.01
1    ABC 2017-07-04      9.01      9.59        0.91
```

Answer (score 0):

It is it is great that your offset is only one day. Then you can do something like the following:

```
mask = esh['reported_time_code'] == 'AMC'
# The mask is basically an array of 0 and 1's \
  all we have to do is to convert them into timedelta objects standing for \
  the number of days to offset

offset = mask.values.astype('timedelta64[D]')
# The D inside the bracket stands for the unit of time to which \
  you want to attach your number. In this case, we want [D]ays.

esh['date'] = esh['reported_date'] + offset
esh.merge(sph, on=['ticker', 'date']).drop(['reported_date', 'reported_time_code'], \
                                           axis=1, inplace=True)
```